# trigger change event into click event VanillaJS

Tags: javascript, events, typescript

I'm currently working on a little plugins wrote on typescript and "compiled" into VanillaJS ES5.

I want before publishing a first version to fire a change event when the user click into an element. I want to pass a value in this event too.

I already tried to do something like that to create the event :

```
private _parentElement: HTMLDivElement;
private _changeEvent: Event;

this._changeEvent = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
this._changeEvent.initEvent("change", false, true);
```

And this to fire it :

```
this._parentElement.dispatchEvent(this._changeEvent);
```

To catch the Event I use this code :

```
addEventListener("onchange", function(e){
        console.log(e)
    });
```

if someone have the solution, I will appreciate :)

Comment: `"onchange"` should be `"change"`

Comment: if you want points, put an answer, thanks